# Problem with SELECT FOR UPDATE - whole table is locked instead row?

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, spring-boot

I have this locking method (New TX) on Spring boot application and SQL Server, Java. Is it possible that this locks whole Car entity in database? Because other thread that wants to lock other carId is hanging. Moreover it seems to work on one node and problems are on external server. Could it be related to SQL Server configuration?

```
 @Override
    public void lockCar(Long entityId) {
        Map<String, Object> properties = getLockProperties();
        entityManager.find(Car.class, entityId, LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE, properties);
        Car car = carRepository.findById(entityId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new EntityIdNotFoundException(Car.class, String.valueOf(entityId)));

        if (iCarLocked(car)) {
            throw new EntityLockedException(Car.class, entityId);
        }
       
        car.setLockedDate(LocalDateTime.now());
       
    }
```

In logs I see:

> select car0_.id as id1_6_0_, car0_.action as aktion2_6_0_ from car
> car0_ with (updlock, holdlock, rowlock) where car0_.id=?

So is it locking whole table or row only?

Comment: It's requesting a `ROWLOCK`, that doesn't mean it takes one. If multiple rows are involved SQL Server may choose to escalate a `ROWLOCK` to a `PAG(e)LOCK`, or if too many pages are involved a `TABLOCK`.

Comment: But would I see it in logs ? How to check it to be sure? Only one entity is locked by me programatically in this transaction as u see in above code. Besides, if it cannot be confirmed maybe I should switch to NO_WAIT strategy, would it be safest ? I don't want other threads waiting to lock their own entitityIds... Thats why all of this should only lock one row or maybe NO_WAIT strategy would be better..

Comment: @AlwaysLearning - I don't think that row locks escalate to page locks. If a lock escalation threshold has been exceeded from having too many row locks, it will escalate to a table lock.

Comment: Thanks very much for all comments. I found other reasons for delays of data processing and it is not related with db locks fortunatelly, but with too little resources for taskExecutor. And I learned that this ROWLOCK is only an attempt and the mssql server decides what to lock :) The other thread was not running at all, log was lying, it was scheduled but never run due to lack of resources, and I was thinking it was hanged because of db lock.